# Concurrent read access to Pickle file

Tags: python, flask

I have a web-app developed with Flask as its backend.

I have a case where I prefer to use dictionary stored as Pickle, instead of using MySQL table.

My question is: Should I expect unexpected behavior when the app tries to read the .pkl concurrently? (e.g. two users at the very same time)

This is how my app accesses the Pickle file:

```py
# Get data from dictionary pickle
  with open(Path.cwd() / 'reports' / 'example_dict.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    updated_dict = pickle.load(f)
    feature_1 = updated_dict.get('feature_1')
```

Comment: If the file is only read concurrently there shouldn't be an issue. If you're writing into it at the same time, there will be many issues. Either way, it seems pretty inefficient to read a file over and over again, wouldn't you rather have it loaded into memory? (if it's not changing)

Comment: Thank you @OferSadan The file is changing every few hours. In this case, I'd have to restart my app in order to update the file in memory, right? Regarding the efficiency, it takes me 0.00035 seconds on avg. to read and get the data I need from the Pickle, this is why I chose this method over standard RDBMS.

Comment: In that case just reading from it concurrently shouldn't be an issue, but you have to think how to "lock" it while it is being written into

Comment: I never really write directly to the Pickle file. I create a new updated file on another server, then, every few hours the other server sends the pickle file with SFTP to the production server and essentially replaces the Pickle. Do you think this process is robust enough?

Comment: An alternative approach is to let your Flask app read the Pickle once at startup into memory. Then add a SIGHUP handler that re-reads the Pickle when a HUP signal is received. Then you can change the Pickle externally whenever you like and when you want the Flask app to use the new values, send it a HUP signal with `kill -SIGHUP <flask pid>`. Other signals are available, e.g. `SIGUSR1/SIGUSR2`

Comment: If you are updating the Pickle file via `sftp`, consider transferring it as `XYZ.pkl.upload` and, when complete and successful, renaming to `XYZ.pkl` which will be an atomic operation and you won't end up with two inconsistent halves of different versions of your file when Flask reads it.